# Filtering out data for sql android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a strings that contains c++ codes.

these codes might contain a single or double inverted quotes and many such thing,

I want to filter out these characters before executing the sql to insert this into the SQLite Database (Android) so, what java code should i run to do that without disturbing/distorting the c++ code, so that when i read the sql database the code should be as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter (replace with nothing) when extracting the data using SQL.

e.g. such a query could be :-

```
SELECT replace(replace(col1,'''',''),'"','') FROM cpluspluscode;
```

- where the respective column is **col1** and the table is **cpluspluscode**.

The following is an example showing how this works:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cpluspluscode;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cpluspluscode (col1 TEXT);
INSERT INTO cpluspluscode VALUES('''mytext'' "other text"');
SELECT * FROM cpluspluscode;
SELECT replace(replace(col1,'''',''),'"','') AS filtered FROM cpluspluscode;
```

The results from the above are :-

Without filtering :-

[image]

Filtered :-

[image]

- The above takes advantage of the SQLite **replace** core function [replace(X,Y,Z)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace)

#### Unicode

If you wanted the to do the above using unicode then you could use :-

```
SELECT replace(replace(col1,char(0034),''),char(39),'') AS filtered FROM cpluspluscode;
```

- This utilises the SQLite **char** core function (see link above).
- The **unicode** core function can be used to find the unicode for a character (again see link above).

#### Android Example

Assuming a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper is **DatabaseHelper** and this creates the table as per :-

```
public static final String TABLE_CPLUSPLUSCODE = "cpluspluscode";
public static final String COLUMN1 = "col1";

.........

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String crtcpp = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CPLUSPLUSCODE + "(" +
            COLUMN1 + " TEXT" +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(crtcpp);
}
```

And **DatabaseHelper** includes the methods :-

```
public long cppInsert(String value) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN1,value);
    return db.insert(TABLE_CPLUSPLUSCODE,null,cv);
}

public Cursor getFiltered() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{"replace(replace(" + COLUMN1 + ",'''',''),'\"','') AS " + COLUMN1};
    return db.query(TABLE_CPLUSPLUSCODE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
}

public Cursor getUnfiltered() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(TABLE_CPLUSPLUSCODE,null,null,null,null, null, null);
}
```

**Then using the following** (in an Activity) :-

```
    DatabaseHelper mDBHlp = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    mDBHlp.cppInsert("''mydata'' \" other data\"");
    Cursor csr1 = mDBHlp.getUnfiltered();
    while (csr1.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("CSR1DATA",csr1.getString(csr1.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN1)));
    }
    csr1.close();
    Cursor csr2 = mDBHlp.getFiltered();
    while (csr2.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("CSR2DATA",csr2.getString(csr2.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN1)));
    }
```

**Results in :-**

```
09-05 04:39:14.003 3471-3471/so52115977.so52115977 D/CSR1DATA: ''mydata'' " other data"
09-05 04:39:14.003 3471-3471/so52115977.so52115977 D/CSR2DATA: mydata  other data
```

i.e. the second line is filtered accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Works like a charm